# Is it possible to connect from esp8266 module over HTTPS protocol?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

Before I will implementing some server application for Arduino client I should know:

Is it possible to connect from esp8266 module to end-point over HTTPS protocol?

Any links of tutorials are welcome.

Thank in advance.

Comment: yes, it is possible. there are examples in IDE Examples menu

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. Try this one tutorial.
https://circuits4you.com/2019/01/10/esp8266-nodemcu-https-secured-get-request/